# SAGA hydrology toolbox Error: select a library

Tags: qgis, dem, qgis-processing, saga

I am having trouble getting the SAGA hydrology toolbox running. Here when I try to fill sinks in the DEM a series of errors are flagged in the log file. This includes for 'select a library', 'DEM' and 'input file'. Load grid also fails (see log file below).

I'm using SAGA 2.3.2 and QGIS 3.4.3

---

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Fill sinks' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'DEM' : 'C:/Users/cbroderick/Downloads/srtm_35_02_ASCII/srtm_35_02.asc', 'MINSLOPE' : 0.01, 'RESULT' : 'C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/5ba9f4f078044c1bae470dfcd5f06f6e/RESULT.sdat' }

io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/4d7bb3df467f4247aa6359cb5b93f904/srtm3502.sgrd" -FILES "C:\Users\cbroderick\Downloads\srtm_35_02_ASCII\srtm_35_02.asc"
ta_preprocessor "Fill Sinks (Planchon/Darboux, 2001)" -DEM "C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/4d7bb3df467f4247aa6359cb5b93f904/srtm3502.sgrd" -MINSLOPE 0.01 -RESULT "C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/5ba9f4f078044c1bae470dfcd5f06f6e/RESULT.sdat"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps\saga-ltr

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\WINDOWS\system32>PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\qt5\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps\saga-ltr;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\WINDOWS\system32>saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/4d7bb3df467f4247aa6359cb5b93f904/srtm3502.sgrd" -FILES "C:\Users\cbroderick\Downloads\srtm_35_02_ASCII\srtm_35_02.asc"
Error: select a library
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)


68 loaded tool libraries (630 tools):
- climate_tools
- contrib_perego
- db_odbc
- db_pgsql
- docs_html
- garden_3d_viewer
- garden_fractals
- garden_games
- garden_learn_to_program
- garden_webservices
- grid_analysis
- grid_calculus
- grid_calculus_bsl
- grid_filter
- grid_gridding
- grid_spline
- grid_tools
- grid_visualisation
- imagery_classification
- imagery_isocluster
- imagery_maxent
- imagery_photogrammetry
- imagery_segmentation
- imagery_svm
- imagery_tools
- io_esri_e00
- io_gps
- io_grid
- io_grid_image
- io_shapes
- io_shapes_dxf
- io_table
- io_virtual
- pj_georeference
- pj_geotrans
- pj_proj4
- pointcloud_tools
- pointcloud_viewer
- shapes_grid
- shapes_lines
- shapes_points
- shapes_polygons
- shapes_tools
- shapes_transect
- sim_cellular_automata
- sim_ecosystems_hugget
- sim_erosion
- sim_fire_spreading
- sim_hydrology
- sim_ihacres
- sim_qm_of_esp
- sim_rivflow
- statistics_grid
- statistics_kriging
- statistics_points
- statistics_regression
- ta_channels
- ta_compound
- ta_hydrology
- ta_lighting
- ta_morphometry
- ta_preprocessor
- ta_profiles
- ta_slope_stability
- table_calculus
- table_tools
- tin_tools
- tin_viewer

type -h or --help for further information


C:\WINDOWS\system32>saga_cmd ta_preprocessor "Fill Sinks (Planchon/Darboux, 2001)" -DEM "C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/4d7bb3df467f4247aa6359cb5b93f904/srtm3502.sgrd" -MINSLOPE 0.01 -RESULT "C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/5ba9f4f078044c1bae470dfcd5f06f6e/RESULT.sdat"
Error: input file [C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/4d7bb3df467f4247aa6359cb5b93f904/srtm3502.sgrd]
Error: DEM
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: ta_preprocessor
library : Preprocessing
tool : Fill Sinks (Planchon/Darboux, 2001)
author : Copyrights (c) 2003 by Volker Wichmann
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________

Load grid: C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/4d7bb3df467f4247aa6359cb5b93f904/srtm3502.sgrd...
failed

Usage: saga_cmd ta_preprocessor 3 [-DEM <str>] [-RESULT <str>] [-MINSLOPE <double>]
-DEM:<str> DEM
Grid (input)
-RESULT:<str> Filled DEM
Grid (output)
-MINSLOPE:<double> Minimum Slope [Degree]
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
Default: 0.010000

C:\WINDOWS\system32>exit
Execution completed in 13.51 seconds
Results:
{'RESULT': 'C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/5ba9f4f078044c1bae470dfcd5f06f6e/RESULT.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/cbroderick/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f1fe9d24ac6c4b08972f8ddd5f612ef7/5ba9f4f078044c1bae470dfcd5f06f6e/RESULT.sdat</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Then [edit] your question to focus on a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the error you're seeing.

Comment: This error was already [reported](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/589) and fixed in version 2.3.2-4 of the `saga-ltr` package.

Comment: It's not saga-ltr bug. But the version of GDAL library:
QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.4.13-2-Setup-x86_64.exe   ---> gdal ver 3.0.? saga not works
QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.4.13-1-Setup-x86_64.exe  ----> gdal ver 2.?.? saga works

Comment: Any feedback on successful solutions? I tried several versions of QGIS standalone: 3.2.3, 3.10, 3.4.13 ltr)
as well as OSGeo4W setup: downgrade saga to 2.3.2-3, qgis to 3.4.13-1, gdal to 3.0.2-3 Also tried David Galt's solution involving hidden folders but the problem persists. I always performed clean installations. I'm on Windows 10. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The version of the `saga-ltr` package compiled in the stand-alone installer of QGIS 3.4.3 has that bug. It can't read the io_gdal library.

This specific bug was already fixed in version 2.3.2-4 of that package.

Also you will have some other important issues in that version. Many of that already fixed too.

I do not know how to update the package in the stand-alone version.

---

I recommend you perform a complete uninstall (this includes removing registry keys and the *C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roamming (and Local)\QGIS 3.4* folders after uninstalling), and using the OSGeo4W Network installer instead.

When a new version of a package comes out, it may be possible that it has some issue, errors that are reported and corrected in the following days, but that the stand-alone installer does not allow or becomes quite complicated to repair.

With the Network installer you can perform a basic installation first, of QGIS, GRASS and SAGA, and then periodically run the Setup tool in advanced mode to keep all the packages updated. The same as installing or uninstalling specific packages quite easily.

It is true that one sometimes finds a problem that is difficult to solve, and would rather have kept QGIS 3.2 working somewhere, for example. It is the disadvantage of staying updated. Also take my advice as what it is, and decide whether to take it or let it go.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, many thanks for your help. I will try installing QGIS and SAGA using the OSGeo4W Network installer.

Comment: Hi Ciaran, you are welcome. Success!

Comment: @CiaranBroderick please accept this answer if it solved your issue

Comment: It is not saga-ltr bugs but is the version of GDAL that make difference:
QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.4.13-2-Setup-x86_64.exe ---> GDAL ver. 3.0.6  
saga don't load io_gdal library
QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.4.13-1-Setup-x86_64.exe ---> GDAL ver. 2.?.?
saga works!

Comment: @natan Hi, the bug referred to in this January 31 answer was a dependency issue in the library saga-ltr 2.3.2-2 and saga-ltr 2.3.2-3, which was delivered along with QGIS version 3.4.3 and I had reported on OSGeo on January 7, and had been resolved in just a couple of days: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/589. If you found a similar dependency error in the versions of QGIS 3.4.13-1 and / or 3.4.13-2, the community would appreciate it if you reported it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have troubles with the SAGA algorithm Edge Detection (Vigra) because the error referred in this post is happening.
I have QGIS 3.18 (installed with OSGeo4W) and the SAGA version is 2.3.2-4. I see that in some posts, in this version, the algorithms worked. However in my case still fo not working.

What can be the solution?